# How to add No Results found to Android Database query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm successfully doing a search query on my `SQLite` Database in my Android app, except that the method as I've written it doesn't do anything if there are no results found. I'm not real fluent in writing DB queries, and so I can't figure out where to put, or how to write something like

```
if(cursor = null){
String noresultStr = "No Results found";
}
```

Here's the method as I've written it:

```
    public Cursor searchDB(String searchTermStr) {
    String[] parts = searchTermStr.split(" ");
    String queryString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        queryString += KEY_TITLE + " LIKE '%" + parts[i] + "%' OR ";
        queryString += KEY_BODY + " LIKE '%" + parts[i] + "%' OR ";
        queryString += KEY_KEYWORDS + " LIKE '%" + parts[i] + "%'";
        if (i != (parts.length - 1)) {
            queryString += " OR ";
        }
    }

    return mDb.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SDF,
            KEY_CAL_DATE, KEY_PATH, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_KEYWORDS },
            queryString, null, null, null, null, null);

}
```

Comment: are you trying to display a "no result" message on your screen? if so you should check `setEmptyView()` of your `ListView` or `setEmptyText()` of your `ListFragment`

Answer (score 0):

If there are no results found, an empty `Cursor` is returned. This is how to check it:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SDF,
        KEY_CAL_DATE, KEY_PATH, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_KEYWORDS },
        queryString, null, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
    String noresultStr = "No Results found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unaware of `setEmptyView()`, so thank you **A.A** for suggesting I look into it. I didn't have to modify the method I use to search the DB, I just added a `TextView` to my DBSearch Activity like so:

```
final ListView list_LV = (ListView) searchRootView.findViewById(R.id.ssisearch_list_lv);
list_LV.setEmptyView(searchRootView.findViewById(R.id.ssiempty_list_tv));
```

... and I get the result I wanted.